# Codeigniter initialize() function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have moved my CodeIgniter website from my development sever to the live server(VPS). It is working perfectly in my server. However in my live sever it showing only blank page nothing else neither any error nor any kind of warning.

I have break the code and get into the controller file of the system folder, and i have echo the code on every line and the find that the system was break from `$this->load->initialize();`function in the main constructor.

I have well configured the all config file such as `database.php`, `config.php`, `route.php`, but still didn't find where I am going wrong.

Comment: Enable error reporting and try again, then add the error you get here.

Comment: I have already did that, my working environment is itself "Development", but not any success, nothing is showing in the browser.

Comment: My guess is that the error reporting handler is overwritten somewhere. You have to follow the http request call chain to find where this is done, find the error and fix it.

Comment: Without the error, this question is too vague and *unanswerable*.

Comment: Thnx of reply and sorry for my weak english, i have echo the temporary string in my default controller and it's break before the parent::__construct(); i have checked and find that the $this->load->initialize(); is not working in the system>>controller.php.

Comment: I know Mark but it is, but I am unable to figured out the reason why it's not working, and I had spend my whole day just for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84675/discussion-between-susain-and-mark).

Comment: @Susain If you are using database then please check in you php.ini whether mysql or mysqli extension is installed and enabled or not.

Comment: I have another application build in the CodeIgniter with the same database and that working fine.

Comment: @HKumar I met the same problem. Have you solve this problem?

Comment: solved by change extension_dir in php.ini config file. mysql extension was not properly config.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->load->initialize();` loads some libraries at the very parent class, **dbdriver** is 1 of that packages so if you are using php7.2, 7.3, 7.4 change line

> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = '**mysql**';
>
> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = '***mysqli***';

in your codeigniter `database.php` file.

mysql functions become depracated in php >= 7, you should use msqli (*i - improved*)